# Does Microsoft Speech REST API have limitation of audio length

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am using **Microsoft Speech Recognition - REST API** to convert audio files to text. I am able to get text from the speech but only part of it.

If I use audio file of length greater than 50 seconds. It just return text result for the first 50 seconds only and anything after 50 seconds is ignored. Is there any limitation of audio length or am I missing something?

Code sample: https://oxfordportal.blob.core.windows.net/speech/doc/recognition/Program.cs

Your help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Bishwa

Comment: you might want to give IBM's STT service a try, you can push hours of audio data in a single request... demo: https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [here](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#user-content-access-the-speech-service-endpoint) says:

> Your application must endpoint the audio to determine start and end of speech, which in turn is used by the service to determine the start and end of the request. You may not upload more than 10 seconds of audio in any one request and the total request duration cannot exceed 14 seconds.

So that suggests that you lucky to be getting 50 seconds.
Instead you should be cutting your audio up into smaller chunks and making multiple requests.

Comment: Hi Buh Buh, Thanks for your reply.  I have set SendChuncked property of HttpWebRequest as true. I am sending audio in smaller chunks (for example 1024 bytes in example code).